# Edit an iframe via FTP

Tags: php, html, iframe, ftp, edit

I have an iframe that loads a remote page (not hosted on the same domain). I would like to edit the contents of the page, but of course, this is not possible, since I don't have permissions.

So, I was wondering, if I have FTP access to the site, would there be a work around to the problem? With FTP, I could copy the files of the site over to my domain, and edit them via an iframe. But I was wondering if there is an alternate method.

Comment: that whole post was a little unreadable. but in short **no**, if i think i understood it correctly

Comment: @Neal, well then. You didn't understand him at all.

Comment: The iframe is a WYSIWYG, in case you were wondering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, **yes**. If you had FTP access to the site you could do it in theory.

Basically, something like:

```
// I used jQuery to speed up writing ajax code, really it could be anything else
jQuery.get('?refresh',function(){ // this function is called when the request finishes
    // force the iframe to do a complete refresh (hence the random token)
    jQuery('#iframe').attr('src','http://targetsite.com/somefile.php?r='+Math.random());
});
```

And:

```
// if the variable in question was set...
if(isset($_REQUEST['refresh'])){
    // the following requires "allow_url_fopen" config to be on
    // otherwise, you could use any other PHP FTP library
    file_put_contents('ftp://username:password@targetsite.com/somefile.php','Hello');
}
```

Comment: Okay. So, I'm guessing you still wouldn't be able to modify any of the contents of the iframe through JavaScript? I was hoping I could edit the page (as a WYSIWYG) through JavaScript, and then when they save, it saves their changes via FTP.

Comment: For example, since permissions are denied for external domains, I was wondering if you could use FTP to load the page, so it wouldn't matter who owned the document.

Comment: Have you even looked at my code? When the iframe refreshes, it shows the new code that's just been updated via FTP! **Remember:** you can **set** the URL (and force a refresh) but not **get** it. Good news is, you don't need to.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was hoping for more direct control, through JavaScript. For instance, being able to drag an element in the iframe's site to a new location. I see, that with your solution, it would be possible to do this, but not as easily as simply adding a drag method via JavaScript. Do you get what I'm saying?

Comment: That's impossible to do (the drag idea) not because of cross-site issues, but simply because dragging wasn't ever meant to be achievable in browsers. There are no standards that even touch over this concept. Though arguably, many Mozilla people seem to call half-cooked messes in Firefox "standards / standard features".  That said, I seem to recall that you could drag & drop text and indeed elements into read sources. Maybe you might want to experiment with that. However, this is something entirely irrelevant to what you asked in the first place.

Comment: Ummm. I have an element dragging script already written that works for non-cross-domain iframes. So, I'm not quite sure what you were trying to say. But, from what I'm gathering, it is impossible to modify an off-site iframe with JavaScript. Is that right? The only way you can do it is by reloading a modified version of the original page. Editing of the actual iframe element isn't possible.

Comment: @Azmisov - That depends on the iframe content. If you can modify the iframe via FTP, you can make it work in other ways. For example, since you seem to want to break cross-domain, there are many ways to do this. The common issue is that people doing this usually can't change the iframe content manually, but if you can, you could do this via specialized JS.

Comment: As to dragging, it's as I said. If you having some dragging script, it's not thanks to browser-based API. As I said, the only dragging specs are the current messes/experiments by the Mozilla team.

Answer (score 0):

Why use iFrames? If you need to load the content of a page hosted on another server, you could  grab its content with cURL or some of the PHP file wrappers, e.g. the PHP [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function. Viola!

If you used `readfile(..)` you can also make edits to the file content you've loaded before you display it. If you have permission, you could also use `include()` to read the file via HTTP if you are certain that a valid PHP file will be returned from your request.

Comment: I don't know that the `include` would _cause_ XSS issues as much as it could potentially be vulnerable to them. It really depends on the purpose of the file he's including.

Comment: `include()` is even worse, since it pertains executing code from a 3rd party. Anyone between the two parties can modify the code in transit and "hack" the server.